In addition to [scanning baggage], the system can also be used [to unlock smartphones].-Does "scanning baggage" correspond to "to unlock smartphones"?
We know that "in addition to" is followed by a noun. But the noun part should be have the same part of the speech as the part of the main clause that it corresponds to. They have to be the parallel structure.
For example,
Example 1

In addition to [playing games], I also [read books] and [go to the gym].

They are a parallel structure.
Example 2

In addition to [games], I also play [cards].

They are a parallel structure.
How about this one?
Example 3

In addition to [scanning baggage], the system can also be used [to unlock smartphones].

Does "scanning baggage" correspond to "to unlock smartphones"?
Example 4

In addition to [talking to friends], the smartphone can also be used [to watch videos].

Does "talking to friends" correspond to "to watch videos"?

We play games with cards, so (2) needs board games or video games to make sense.

Can you provide a reference stating the grammatical rule you mention? The two parts don't need to have the same part of speech. There's no ellipsis, and "In addition to X" is a separate prepositional phrase. It's different with "The system can be used to scan baggage and in addition to unlock smartphones" where "scan" and "unlock" both follow "can be used".

There is some confusion in your question. "in addition to" doesn't need verb -verb or gerund - gerund as per Cambridge dictionary. Please check if your information is correct.
in addition (to)
phrase
Add to word list
B1
as well (as):
In addition to his apartment in Manhattan, he has a villa in Italy and a castle in Scotland.
All employees receive paid vacation and sick leave. In addition, we offer a range of benefits for new parents.
She's a fitness instructor in addition to being a full-time student..

You don't need in addition to AND also.


We know that "in addition to" is followed by a noun. But the noun part should be have the same part of the speech as the part of the main clause that it corresponds to. They have to be the parallel structure.

No, not really. It isn't like having a compound subject or object. In these sentences:


I like to read and going to the gym.
To live a good life and having fun are my goals.


... the lack of parallel construction is a problem, because in these sentences we have two things taking the role of subject (in the one) and of object (in the other). But in the sentences you've given, the "in addition to" phrase doesn't share a grammatical role as subject or object with the rest of the sentence. It's important that the sentence has ideas that make sense together (e.g. we don't want "In addition to winning the footrace, he can't swim"), but we don't have to use parallel grammatical parts. All that matters is that the main clause is grammatically valid, that the referent of "in addition to" functions as a noun, and that the entire idea makes sense.

"In addition to [friends], the smartphone can also be used [to watch videos]." This appears to be saying another thing. It sounds like the smartphone can be used to watch friends, which sounds kind of weird.
Compared to that, "In addition to [talking to friends], the smartphone can also be used [to watch videos]" clearly states that talking to friends and watching videos are two key functions of a smartphone.

@VinceL Yup. I'd argue this has nothing to do with grammar and simply with making sense. Similarly, "In addition to [friends], the smartphone can connect you to [relatives]" works fine.

"In addition to [praying for good luck], Japanese mochi is also eaten [to celebrate the festival]." Does this basically mean Japanese mochi can be eaten to pray for good luck and to celebrate the festival?
